# Removing unwanted numbers after delimiter in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have a table like this below:

```
Smartphone  Manufacturer    Region
iPhone 12   Apple   US
Galaxy S20  Samsung EUROPE:1233
        
Galaxy Note 10  Samsung EUROPE;345
Galaxy Note 9   Samsung EUROPE1234
Pixel   Google  US
        
Moto g3 Motorola    ASIA
```

Effectively, I want to remove everything that is not a valid letter in the region section. For example `EUROPE:1233` is invalid and should instead be just `EUROPE`. I also dont want any numbers such as `EUROPE1234` and instead just want `EUROPE` on its own. Is there a formula that I can use such that it automatically corrects all the rows in the Region in one go?

Also, is there a quick way to remove empty rows?

Any help will mean a lot!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding removing blank rows, try google **use the Go to function to remove blank rows**. Regarding correcting the region, how many regions do you have? Would it be easy to come up with a list of all the regions? This can be done by searching for the correct region name from the list and showing the correct region name in a new column. If you want to correct the region name directly within the source column, you will need **VBA** to achieve that (or use **PowerQuery**)

Comment: Excel or Google Sheets? They're not the same. Please fix the question tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula

```
=QUERY({B1:C,ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(D1:D,"[[:alpha:]]+")))},"where Col1 is not null",1)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow thanks, this looks complicated to me sorry. I tried using something like this `=LEFT(B5,FIND(";",B5)-1)` but then got errors in places where it was just like `US`, `EUROPE`, `ASIA`. Sorry to be annoying but is there a simpler way to do using LEFT command on all of it?

Comment: I gave you solution but you don't want it. The way you try will never work. LEFT will never work. Why not accept solution I gave? You find it complicated? Copy/paste, change ranges. Simple. Or give link to test sheet and I fix it for you. Also read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)