# Remove all rows with specific values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Essentially what I am trying to do is remove some rows that match a list of names. In my case, I want to remove any phones made by these manufacturers:

```
Samsung
Huawei
Sony-Ericcson
HTC
LG
Blackberry
```

This is my original table:

```
Smartphone  Manufacturer    Region
iPhone 12   Apple   US
Galaxy S20  Samsung EUROPE
Galaxy Note 10  Samsung EUROPE
Galaxy Note 9   Samsung EUROPE
Pixel   Google  US
Moto g3 Motorola    ASIA
N95 Nokia   ASIA
N-Gage  Nokia   ASIA
P30 Huawei  ASIA
P40 Huawei  ASIA
5t  One Plus    ASIA
Xperia X10  Sony-Ericcson   EUROPE
6t  One Plus    EUROPE
w810i   Sony-Ericcson   EUROPE
w910i   Sony-Ericcson   EUROPE
Hero    HTC ASIA
HD2 HTC US
Curve   Blackberry  US
3L  Alcatel EUROPE
SF71    Benq-Siemens    EUROPE
W41 LG  EUROPE
```

Is there also a way for me to get all unique instances of the manufacturers so its like this:

```
Apple
Samsung
Google
Motorola
Nokia
Huawei
One Plus
Sony-Ericcson
HTC
Blackberry
Alcatel
Benq-Siemens
LG
```

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Excel and Google Sheets are not the same. Please fix the question tags.

Comment: "Excel and Google Sheets are not the same. Please fix the question tags." We say before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66879572/removing-unwanted-numbers-after-delimiter-in-excel). Please understand. They are NOT the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Excel:

1. Click the first cell inside the manufacturer column (B2),
2. Select all cells inside this column (Ctrl + Shift + Down Arrow),
3. Ctrl + F to start searching,
4. Enter the first name (Samsung) and choose: Find All,
5. Use Ctrl + A shortcut to select all selected cells (it will select all cells with this name),
6. Press (Ctrl + -) to show the Delete window,
7. Choose Entire Row to remove rows with this name,
8. Repeat for other manufacturers.

For removing duplicate values, there is information how to do it:
https://excel.officetuts.net/en/formulas/excel-list-unique-values

Comment: If it's working for you, please mark the answer as correct.