# How do I reference two different variables and a third date range using COUNTIFS

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, countif

Within a google sheet, on tab 2 I have column A of dates and column B of words. On tab 1, I have a date range in two cells. I am trying to populate the cell if column A falls within the date range of tab 1 and also has the specified word.

[Variables to check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFAzW.png)

[Date cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Bvb7.png)

Comment: Matt. Look, [look](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888826/remove-all-rows-with-specific-values) what others give. Be generous with data for help you.

Comment: What research you did till now? Did you come up with any formula? Please consider providing a copy of the spredasheet you are working on so that your issue can be understood.

Comment: Here is an example on a google sheet of what I am trying to do:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XitcT4jADU6okVszdu1aEGZjfqZoNqNZVFXyI8eN09A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Matt, I posted an answer. I'm unsure whether you wanted to return the number of matches or the data itself, in which case the second approach would be more appropriate, but would require a modification. I'll wait for your clarification.

Comment: The first one was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B2:B,"toured",Sheet2!A2:A,">="&A2,Sheet2!A2:A,"<="&A3)
```

[image]

#### Using QUERY:

```
=QUERY(Sheet2!A2:B,"SELECT COUNT(A) WHERE B='toured' AND A >= date '"&TEXT(A2,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' AND A <= date '"&TEXT(A3,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' label COUNT(A) ''")
```

[image]

#### Note:

In the spreadsheet you shared, somehow the `toured` in cell `B4` is not getting detected as such, resulting in the returned value being `2`. Please rewrite `toured` in that cell in order to make sure `3` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)